# trouble with my random number games round system

Tags: python

```
import random

rnd=0
guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')
myName = input()

for i in range (10):
    print('---round' +str(rnd+1) +'---')

    number = random.randint(1, 20)
    print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

    while guessesTaken <= 5:
    ***~the error ^^^~***
        print('Take a guess.') 
        guess = input()
        guess = int(guess)

        guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

        if guess < number:
            print('Your guess is too low.') 

        if guess > number:
            print('Your guess is too high.')

        if guess == number:
            break

    if guess == number:
        guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
        print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

    if guess != number:
        number = str(number)
        print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)


    rnd=rnd+1
```

I am trying to put a round system into this guessing game but at round two after it says "Well, aidan, I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20." there is an error saying

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

from line 15.

Comment: Reading the error message surely `guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)` seems suspect? Maybe read up on the various string formatting options, or at least assign the string to a separate variable for the concatenation.

Comment: I just tried that and it made it worse, when I did that it failed before the first round finished

Comment: Tried... *what*, exactly? Give a [mcve].

Comment: Or he could just use `print` by itself @jonrsharpe: `print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ', guessesTaken, ' guesses!')`. Or he could just use `str` without using a variable - albeit it would be a bit ugly. There are many options, OP, do a bit of research and choose one.

Comment: @ChristianDean feasibly, but that means they can't get the spacing the way they want.

Comment: True @jonrsharpe. OP should probably just search up string formatting techniques like you said. A good place to start OP would be: https://pyformat.info.

Comment: no its not any of that I don't think as when I run it without the rounds which I've defined with rnd it doesn't work, without that its fine. (I might just be missing something obvious I've inly been really doing python for a couple months)

Comment: ill try and research it then, thank you for the advice

Comment: Can you be more specific @dakaidan? Perhaps modify your question. What me and jonrsharpe are telling you is that you need to either find a way to format `guessInteger` into the string you want to display _without_ changing it's type, or assign the result of `str(guessInteger)` to a variable, and use that in your `print` call instead.

Answer (score 2):

When you are saying `guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)`, the original `guessesTaken` variable, which was an **integer**, becomes a **string**. Then, when you're verifying a second time your `while` loop condition `guessTaken <= 5`, you are comparing a **string** with an **integer**... which is not something that is *supported*, as your error stated `'<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`.

The solution would be, as one stated in the comment, to have a better understanding of string formatting, and printing usage. You don't need to transform entirely your variable (meaning transforming your integer into a string).

You could just do instead of...

```
guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')
```

This :

```
print('Good job, {} ! You guessed my number in {} guesses !'.format(myName, guessesTaken))
```

---

Doing this, you are simply printing your variable **as is**, instead of **casting it into another type**. If you would still do it your way (which is **bad**, by the way), you could do...

```
guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')
guessesTaken = int(guessesTaken)
```

Comment: As bonus, if the OP's using Python 3.6 or above, they could use f-strings: `print(f'Good job, {myName} ! You guessed my number in {guessesTaken} guesses !')`.